# How to read nested optional object for an insert statement?

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-mapper

How to read nested optional object for an insert statement?

I have the following classes;

```java
public class MyObj {
    
    private String myField;
    private MyChildObj myChild;
    
    public (String myField, MyChildObj myChild) {
        this.myField = myField;
        this.myChild = myChild;
    }

    public String getMyField() {
        return this.myField;
    }
    
    public Optinal<MyChildObj> getMyChildObj() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.myChild);
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyChildObj {
    
    private String myField2;
    
    public (String myField2) {
        this.myField2 = myField2;
    }

    public String getMyField2() {
        return this.myField2;
    }
}
```

And a mapper like this:

```java
public interface MyMapper {
    @Insert("INSERT INTO `Entity` VALUES(" +
            "#{entity.myField}," +
            "#{entity.myChild.myField2})")
    public int insertEntity(@Param("entity") MyObj entity);
```

With this I get an error like

> There is no getter for property named 'myField2' in 'class
> java.util.Optional'

Do I need a separate TypeHandler for this or is there another solution?

Comment: I think you meant `#{entity.myChildObj.myField2}`. If you actually write `#{entity.myChild.myField2}`, MyBatis accesses the field (which is not `Optional`) directly, so that exception won't be thrown. Also, do you expect `null` for `#{entity.myChildObj.myField2}` when `myChild` is `null`?

Comment: Yes I would expect it to behave the same as if it were not an Optional and `getMyChildObj()` would return `null` instead of an empty Optional. Or exactly the same as if `myChild` was returned directly without the Optional wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the getter name is different from the field name.

```java
private MyChildObj myChild;

public Optional<MyChildObj> getMyChildObj() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(this.myChild);
}
```

In this case, you can access the field directly in a mapper statement because MyBatis can access private field/method [1].

```java
@Insert({
  "INSERT INTO `Entity` VALUES(",
  "#{entity.myField},",
  "#{entity.myChild.myField2})"})
public int insertEntity(@Param("entity") MyObj entity);
```

When the getter has the same name as the field, there needs to be some extra work.

```java
private MyChildObj myChildObj;

public Optional<MyChildObj> getMyChildObj() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(this.myChildObj);
}
```

I'll explain the following three solutions.

1. Define a private getter.
2. Use `<bind>` tag.
3. Create a custom `ObjectWrapper`.

The first one is pretty straight-forward.
Just add a private getter method...

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private MyChildObj getMyChildObjPrivate() {
  return myChildObj;
}
```

...and use it in a mapper statement.

```java
@Insert({
  "INSERT INTO `Entity` VALUES(",
  "#{entity.myField},",
  "#{entity.myChildObjPrivate.myField2})"})
public int insertEntity(@Param("entity") MyObj entity);
```

---

The second solution is a little bit verbose.
In a `<bind>` tag, the expression of `value` attribute is evaluated by [OGNL](https://ognl.orphan.software/), so you can write something like the following.

```java
@Insert({
  "<script>",
  "<bind name='x'",
  "  value='entity.myChildObj.isEmpty() ? null :",
  "  entity.myChildObj.get().myField2'/>",
  "INSERT INTO users VALUES(",
  "#{entity.myField},",
  "#{x})",
  "</script>"})
int insertEntity(@Param("entity") MyObj entity);
```

---

The third solution is to create a custom `ObjectWrapper`.
The following implementation adds a pseudo property `orNull` to `Optional` objects (note: it's not well-tested).

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject;
import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.property.PropertyTokenizer;
import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.ObjectWrapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.ObjectWrapperFactory;

public class MyObjectWrapperFactory implements ObjectWrapperFactory {

  private static String[] pseudoProperties = new String[] {
    "orNull"
  };

  @Override
  public boolean hasWrapperFor(Object object) {
    return object instanceof Optional;
  }

  @Override
  public ObjectWrapper getWrapperFor(MetaObject metaObject, Object object) {
    return new OptionalWrapper((Optional<?>) object);
  }

  private static class OptionalWrapper implements ObjectWrapper {

    Optional<?> optional;

    OptionalWrapper(Optional<?> optional) {
      this.optional = optional;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(PropertyTokenizer prop) {
      String name = prop.getName();
      return switch (name) {
        case "orNull" -> optional.orElse(null);
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Invalid pseudo property name for Optional: '" + name
                + "'; Valid names are ['orNull'].");
      };
    }

    @Override
    public void set(PropertyTokenizer prop, Object value) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public String findProperty(String name, boolean useCamelCaseMapping) {
      return hasPseudoProperty(name) ? name : null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getGetterNames() {
      return pseudoProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSetterNames() {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getSetterType(String name) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getGetterType(String name) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasSetter(String name) {
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasGetter(String name) {
      return hasPseudoProperty(name);
    }

    @Override
    public MetaObject instantiatePropertyValue(String name, PropertyTokenizer prop, ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCollection() {
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object element) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public <E> void addAll(List<E> list) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private static boolean hasPseudoProperty(String name) {
      for (int i = 0; i < pseudoProperties.length; i++) {
        if (pseudoProperties[i].equals(name)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

To register the custom `ObjectWrapperFactory` using MyBatis' XML configuration:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "https://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
  <objectWrapperFactory type="pkg.MyObjectWrapperFactory"/>
  ...
</configuration>
```

If you are using [mybatis-spring-boot](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/), add the following line to the `application.properties` :

```ini
mybatis.configuration.object-wrapper-factory=pkg.MyObjectWrapperFactory
```

The pseudo-property `orNull` returns `null` when the `Optional` is empty.

```java
@Insert({
  "INSERT INTO `Entity` VALUES(",
  "#{entity.myField},",
  "#{entity.myChildObj.orNull.myField2})"})
public int insertEntity(@Param("entity") MyObj entity);
```

---

[1] With JPMS, you may have to open your module to MyBatis.

Comment: I first tried the solution with `ObjectWrapper`. It works also in this case.

But I have another case where `getMyChildObj()` returns directly the object and `getMyField2()` then returns the `Optional`. Then it gave the error that `Optional` cannot be serialized.

I started a new try with `<bind>` and it works fine. For me this is also the better solution, because with `<bind>` I have a very powerful tool, with which I get also complex requirements still solved.

Best thanks!